# What is the difference between Compound statement and Statement form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have just started learning introductory discrete math and I am kind of confused. I can't see the difference between compound statements and statement forms. To me, they look the same according two these 2 definitions:

Compound statement:

> A statement represented by a some combination of statement variables and connectives is called a compound statement.

Statement form:

> Statement form or propositional form is an expression made up of statement variables such as p, q, r and logical connectives that becomes a statement when actual statements are substituted for the component statement variables.

Are they the same thing ? What am I missing here?

Comment: More or less the same...

Comment: More correctly : "Napoleon is a general **and** Fido is a dog" is a (compound) *statement*. The corresponding *statement form* is $p \land q$.

Comment: The compund statement is obtained from the statement form when the actual statements "Napoleon is a general" is substituted for $p$ and "Fido is a dog" for $q$.

Comment: We may say: a *statement form* is : either (i) a statement variable (*atomic* s.f.), or (ii) some combination of statement variables and connectives (*compund* s.f.).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Mauro.

Comment: so the *statement form* is the statement in English, but translated into math symbols (which strips it of the semantics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compound statement: *"It is raining, and if I don't find my umbrella, I will stay at home."*

A statement form corresponding to the above: $r\land(\neg f \to s)$.

A statement that is not compound: *"It is raining."*

A statement form corresponding to the non-compound statement: $r$.

Don't sweat this too much. Once you get to leave the natural-language sentences behind and just focus on the mathematics, both of these concepts will mostly fade back into obscurity, and it will suddenly be okay to call $r\land (\neg f\to s)$ a statement anyway.